# wrap div around text (to create a button) CSS

Tags: css, button, width

I'm a beginner at web design, and I simply couldn't find a way on the web to wrap a div around some text to create a button (I want the div to have fixed height, and the width to vary depeinding on the class's content).
This is what I try to obtain:

[image: first button] [image: second button]

(the images above are made in photoshop)

this is what happens:

[image: home page]

this is the code (both HTML and CSS)

```
<div id="menu">
<font color="white">

        <div class="button">
        Home
        </div>
        <div class="button">
        Image Gallery
        </div>

</font>
</div>
```

.

```
#menu{
 height:30px;
 width:980px;
 background-color:#132f74;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.button{
  background-color: #132f74;
  width:auto;
  height:30px;
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:22px;
}
```

What should I do to obtain the fluid width effect?

Comment: You...want the elements side-by-side? At the width of their content? (`display: inline` or `display: inline-block`). Oh, and the [`<font>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is obsolete. Don't use it, use CSS to style the elements with the appropriate font and appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` and `margin: 5px` to `.buttons`; and `height: 40px` to `#menu`:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/2gg41bjk/2/)

```
#menu {
    height:40px;
    width:980px;
    background-color:#1127ff;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #132f74;
    height:30px;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:22px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**I've changed the `background-color` of `#menu` to show the difference.**

Answer (score 1):

Add padding to your `.button` class, and set `display:` to `inline-block`, like so:

```
.button {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is pretty good. I would use a combination of `float:left` and `padding-right` to make it fit on one line. Optionally, you could include a little separator as well using the `:after` accessor and the `content` CSS property.

```
#menu{
 height:30px;
 width:980px;
 background-color:#132f74;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 clear:both;
}

.button{ 
  background-color: #132f74;
  width:auto;
  height:30px;
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:22px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/* optional - display a separator */
.button:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '|';
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's not yet clear to me what padding and float does, i'll have to look further into it; i chose to use display: inline-block to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
.button{
  background-color: #132f74;
  width:auto;
  height:30px;
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:22px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6y44f7n/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you've been looking for...

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background:#132f74;
}

#menu{
 color:#fff;
 display:inline;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 background:#132f74;
 z-index:2;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.button{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#132f74;
  height:30px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:22px;
}

.button:hover {
    background:#081533;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Image Gallery</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Example</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Another Long Example</a>
    </div>
</div>
```